# Appium Error while running script of unlock apk

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, appium

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\Ramoji\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\build-tools' (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 970 milliseconds

Appium Logs:

```
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"app":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Appium\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\unlock_apk\\unlock_apk-debug.apk","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"39a104ce"},{},{"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Appium\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\unlock_apk\\unlock_apk-debug.apk","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"39a104ce"},"requiredCapabilities":{},"alwaysMatch":{"platformName":"Android"},"firstMatch":[]}]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1509613560405 (14:36:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[Appium] Creating new AndroidDriver (v1.20.0) session
[Appium] Capabilities:
[Appium]   app: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Appium\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\unlock_apk\\unlock_apk-debug.apk'
[Appium]   platformName: 'Android'
[Appium]   deviceName: '39a104ce'
[debug] [AndroidDriver] AndroidDriver version: 1.20.0
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: 30c58492-0ec2-4399-9800-d5813f05d3d1
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Getting Java version
[AndroidDriver] Java version is: 1.8.0_151
[ADB] Checking whether adb is present
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Called deleteSession but bootstrap wasn't active
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\Ramoji\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\build-tools'
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 480 ms - 258
```

Comment: you need to add ANDROID_HOME\platform-tools & ANDROID_HOME\tools paths to your system PATH variable

Answer (score 0):

Please check your ANDROID_HOME as appium is not able to find build tool :

ANDROID_HOME =C:\Users\Ramoji\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk'

In Path environment set location till build-tools directory :
C:\Users\Ramoji\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\build-tools

or %ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools\build-tools.

Also check in Eclipse Eclipse -> Run Configurations -> Environments tab if any wrong path is set

Comment: Thank My dear friend for sharing your suggestion but it didn't worked out well.